# Express.js application bug: validationResult(req) method does not work

Tags: node.js, express, validation

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

Before submitting a new post, of course, I have to *validate the form entries*. I use *express-validator* version 6.3.0.

My addPost controller:

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
    // Form validation rules
    check('title', 'The title field id required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty();
    check('excerpt', 'The excerpt field id required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty();
    check('body', 'The full text field id required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty();

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors.array());
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        res.render('admin/addpost', {
            layout: 'admin/layout',
            website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
            page_heading: 'Dashboard',
            page_subheading: 'Add New Post',
            errors: errors
        });
        req.flash('danger', errors);
        req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
    } else {
        const post = new Post();
        post.title = req.body.title;
        post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
        post.full_text = req.body.body;

        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                req.flash('success', "The post was successfully added");
                req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Post model:

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    short_description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    full_text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    post_image: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    updated_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
});
```

The error messages are nor rendered in the view, which looks like this:

```
<div id="messages" class="text-center">
    <% Object.keys(messages).forEach(function (type) { %>
        <% messages[type].forEach(function (message) { %>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= type %>"><%= message %></div>
        <% }) %>
    <% }) %>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

The index.js file in the root has this code:

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const expressLayouts = require("express-ejs-layouts");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const session = require("express-session");
const app = express();

dotenv.config();

//Conect to MONGODB
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("conected");
  });

mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.log(`DB connection error: ${err.message}`);
});

// Set static directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Set views directory
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

// Set view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// Use Express Layouts
app.use(expressLayouts);

// Morgan Middleware
app.use(morgan("dev"));

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cookieParser());

// Express Sessions Middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: '123',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Express Messages Middleware
app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

// Bring the Dashboard
const dashboardRoute = require("./routes/admin/dashboard");

// Get Dashboard Routes
app.use('/dashboard', dashboardRoute);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your very latest code pushed to the repo?

Comment: @ZeeshanHassanMemon Yes, it is, check it out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.flash('errors', errors.array())
        req.session.save(() => res.redirect('../addpost'));
        //return res.status(400).send(errors.array());
    } else {
            const post = new Post();
                post.title = req.body.title;
                post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
                post.full_text = req.body.body;

            post.save(function(err){
                    if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                            return;
                    } else {
                        req.flash('success', "The post was successfully added");
                        req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
                    }
            });
    }
}
```

**messages.ejs**

```
<div id="messages" class="text-center">
<% Object.keys(messages).forEach(function (type) { %>
    <% messages[type].forEach(function (message) { %>
        <% if (type === 'errors') {%>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= type %>"><%= message.msg %></div>
        <%} else { %>
            <div class="alert alert-<%= type %>"><%= message %></div>
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>
<% }) %>
```

I guess this is what you intended to do

Comment: I have simplified your version of the `messages.ejs` file (other then that, your solutiom is perfect). Have a look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60721302/4512005)**. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering a template then trying to show flash and then redirect again. Change it to this

```
req.flash('danger', errors);
req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
```

Forget the render... It makes no sense for you to have it there. What render does, it renders and returns a template. Therefore your req.flash and redirect never happens or it happens after the header have already been sent.

res.render() definition:

> Renders a view and sends the rendered HTML string to the client.
>   Optional parameters:
>
> locals, an object whose properties define local variables for the
>   view. callback, a callback function. If provided, the method returns
>   both the possible error and rendered string, but does not perform an
>   automated response. When an error occurs, the method invokes next(err)
>   internally.

AND

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
   // Form validation rules
    req.check('title').not().isEmpty().withMessage("The title field is mandatory");
    req.check('body').not().isEmpty().withMessage("The full text field is mandatory");

   const errors = req.validationErrors();
```

Comment: The confirmation messages work well. The validation error messages are the ones that do not work.

Comment: First of all you dont need the redirect and move req.flash above the render

Comment: If there are errors, shouldn't I re-render the form?

Comment: No, you call req.flash and then your template engine checks if there is a flash message and if there are it renders

Comment: Works exactly same as your success

Comment: Also your validation does not work. Change it to the one ive written

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209135/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-tslegaitis).

Answer (score 1):

Try change your `if` statement from this:

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log('there are no validation errors');
} else {
    console.log(errors);
}
```

**To this:**

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
    // Form validation rules
    check('title', '<your error message>')
      .not()
      .isEmpty();
    check('excerpt', '<your error message>')
      .not()
      .isEmpty();
    check('body', '<your error message>')
      .not()
      .isEmpty();

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
       console.log(errors.array());
    }
}
```

---

If you would like to send an response to your front-end replace the `console.log()` command into `res.send()` then parse the answer in your front-end like so:

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.send(errors.array());
    // Can also send an status and catch it
    // By sending res.status(400).send(errors.array());
}
```

Comment: I ger this long error nessage: `{ title:
      { ValidatorError: Path `title` is required.`....

Comment: Hi, if you want the errors to be seen in your front-end , you can return the response with the specific error in the array. just replace the 'console.log' into 'return res.send(errors.array())' then parse them in your front-end

Comment: The template contains and *has to contain* the `messages` variable. The solution does not work.

Comment: In fact, `return res.send(errors.array());` results in... a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

from what i see in the documentation of [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/#basic-guide) you need to provide an array of validation rules(those `checks` at the top of your controller) when you define the route.
It doesn't make much sense for them to be at the top of the request handler since the **express-validator** won't be able to access the context that provides the request to be validated.

So in the router you need something like this:

**router/front-end/posts.js**

```
const validationRules = [// Form validation rules
        check('title', 'The title field id required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
    check('excerpt', 'The excerpt field id required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
 check('body', 'The full text field id required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty()];
// create new post
router.post('/', validationRules, postsController.addPost);
```

**controllers/front-end/posts.js**

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {

        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            console.log(errors.array());
     }

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            res.render('admin/addpost', {
            layout: 'admin/layout',
             website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
             page_heading: 'Dashboard',
             page_subheading: 'Add New Post',
             errors: errors
            });
            req.flash('danger', errors);
            req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
        } else {
                const post = new Post();
                    post.title = req.body.title;
                    post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
                    post.full_text = req.body.body;

                post.save(function(err){
                       if(err){
                          console.log(err);
                          return;
                        } else {
                          req.flash('success', "The post was successfully added");
                          req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
                        }
                });
        }
}
```

Everything else seem ok, at least from the code you posted.

Comment: Isn't it more logical to validate the data (form) in the controller? Isn't this "classic"?

Comment: I'm just wondering how would the `check` method access the request, if no one is sending it as a parameter.
Intuition tells me that validation should happen in a middleware, add some property on the request and pass the execution to the next handler(the controller) where the `validationResult (req)` extracts that property created in the validation middleware.

Comment: I don't know. This is why I have asked the question. But I am almost 100% sure that there should not be any logic in the routes file *except* the routes logic.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a bug with express-validators, it is the way how validators work in case of middlewares.

At the root level create a directory called utils and inside the directory a validation.js file and add your validation code in it:

**utils/validation.js**

```
const { check } = require('express-validator');
exports.addPostCheck = [
    check('title', 'The title field id required')
    .not()
    .isEmpty(),
    check('excerpt', 'The excerpt field id required')
    .not()
    .isEmpty(),
    check('body', 'The full text field id required')
    .not()
    .isEmpty()
];
```

**In the routes/dashboard.js include validation.js**

```
const validator = require('../../utils/validation.js');

Change Line No: 16
From: 
router.post('/post/add', dashboardController.addPost);
To:
router.post('/post/add', validator.addPostCheck, dashboardController.addPost);
```

**In the controllers/admin/dashboard.js**

```
Change Line No: 2
From: 
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
To:
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');

Remove Line Nos 29 to 39.
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55772477/how-to-implement-validation-in-a-separate-file-using-express-validator)

Comment: That is because of line number 39 in controller/dasboard.js, since the response is returned from line number 33, and again you are trying to return the response that is why  you are getting the error `[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.
Fix: Remove line number 39.

Comment: Solved the "Cannot set headers" problem. The validation error messages  still do not render in the *unsubmitted* form's page, though.

Comment: For that I think you should consider @TSlegaitis answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start with this https://express-validator.github.io/docs/ then gradually customise it to fit your need so that you can catch any error along the way.

Comment: The version I use is version 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in index.js to get flash error messages locally in EJS ,

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.messages = req.flash();
    next();
});
```

Comment: I have this as messages middleware: `app.use(flash());
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
      next();
    });`. What is wrong with it? (It works for the conformation messages). Where shall I put your code in the *contex* of my `index.js` file (see qiestion update)?

Comment: app.use(flash()) this allow to save messages in express session , yes i have seen in index.js . two options only iterate  with errors objects or pass flash messages in locals res.locals.messages = req.flash();

Comment: Can you put *your* code in the code I have for `index.js`? (I have tried numerous packages and now I don't know exactly what `index.js` should contain and what not to). Thanks!

Comment: I should use your code instead of which part of my code?

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the solution provided by Saravanakumar T N with a small modification in **messages.ejs**.

I have: this in the controller:

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  const post = new Post();
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    req.flash('danger', errors.array());
    req.session.save(() => res.redirect('../addpost'));
 } else {
    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
    post.full_text = req.body.body;

    post.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            req.flash('success', "The post was successfully added");
            req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
        }
    });
  }
}
```

In the view:

```
<div id="messages" class="text-center">
    <% Object.keys(messages).forEach(function (type) { %>
            <% messages[type].forEach(function (message) { %>
                    <div class="alert alert-success <% if (type === 'danger') { %> alert-dismissible <% } %> alert-<%= type %>">
                        <% if (type === 'danger') { %>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                            <%= message.msg %>
                        <%} else { %>
                            <%= message %>
                        <% } %>
                </div>
            <% }) %>
    <% }) %>
</div>
```